# Podio Importer API call mapping to correct incorrect Relationship Fields between Podio Apps

Tags: api, import, export, xlsx, podio

We're looking for development resources who are familiar with the Podio Importer: https://developers.podio.com/doc/importer/import-app-items-212899

We really just need an example with the right parameters, and below is the use case.

---

Our development team is currently trying to accomplish the cloning of a set of apps from one workspace to another, where all of the relationships fields among these link to each other in the NEW workspace.

We don't want to relink the relationship fields one API call at a time, as that would take hours in some cases.

What this means:

In workspace X person A links to person B and group C. 
In workspace Y, we want person A to link to NEW person B and NEW group C.

We've done this so far in order to accomplish this:

1. Export all .XLSX files for our workspace X apps;
2. Clone all the workspace X apps into workspace Y without content;
3. Import all items WITHOUT relationship data into workspace Y by using workspace X's exported .XLSX files;

The step we're needing help with figuring out now is this:

4. Import all items WITH relationship data in order to update workspace Y's items to establish relationships with the other workspace Y's new cloned items.

We've accomplished bullet 3 easily by using the Importer and passing in the array mapping to the data on each .XLSX file, composed of many of these, for example:

```
{ 
   field_id: FIELD_OF_FIRST_APP_TEXT_FIELD, 
   unique: false, 
   value: { 
     column_id: “5” 
   } 
}
```

But in what comes to the second import just for the RELATIONSHIPS bullet 4, we can't figure out how to do this.

We've done similar to bullet 3, but referencing the app_id, but when we try updating with these, items were not updated with the relationships.

```
{ 
  field_id: FIELD_OF_FIRST_APP_RELATIONSHIP_FIELD, 
  unique: false, 
  value: { 
    column_id: “4”, 
     app_id: NEW_RELATED_CLONED_APP_ID, 
     mappings: [ TBD ] 
   } 
}
```

What we're missing must be the mappings: on this last example.

What/how should we be declaring this as in order to link to the related app item? 
How is the link done?

We've noticed in the exported XLSX files that it seems the exported String for Relationship fields is just the collection of all of the Related items' FIRST string field.

How does this work, exactly?

A mapping has a column_id param, it makes no sense to pass in one more column inside of the mapping because there's no way to “access” the other apps' XLSX?

Comment: Hi Rolando - just want to add our experience in doing similar thing. We have done same setup in https://podiocopy.phases.dk/ but had to update the items one at a time using multiple parses. What we have done is cloned all the source apps directly to the destination including data and then looped through each items and updated the references one by one. We kept all the ids temporarily in a DB to minimize the api calls.

Comment: @Anz Thanks. Is someone from your team free to look at / optimize the approach we took? If so, email rolando.brown@gmail.com. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Podio's importer doesn't provide a way of "reinstating" relationships after export/import of apps.

Those relationship will have to be recreated manually or via the API on a subsequent run.